# How are Google App Engine instances charged?

Tags: google-app-engine

In [GAE doc's billing page](https://code.google.com/appengine/kb/billing.html), it says:

> Instances are charged for their uptime in addition to a 15-minute
>   startup fee, the startup fee covers what it takes for App Engine to
>   bring up and down the instance.

But in [this page](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html), it says this:

> In general, instance usage is billed on an hourly basis based on the
>   instance's uptime. Billing begins when the instance starts and ends
>   fifteen minutes after the instance shuts down.
>
> Billing is slightly different in resident and dynamic instances:
>
> For resident instances, billing ends fifteen minutes after the backend
>   is shut down.
>
> For dynamic instances, billing ends fifteen minutes after the last
>   request has finished processing.

So these 2 expressions confuse me. What is the real billing method for instances?

Comment: The methods sound identical to me?

Comment: These are identical when an instance dies after 15 minutes of no traffic. But according to my experience, an instance can live longer than 15 minutes.